# Docker layer hashes are different between identical fully cached builds

Tags: linux, docker, docker-buildkit

I am seeing different checksums calculated for image layers that should be identical.

This is my dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

ARG ONEAPI_VERSION=2022.1.2
FROM intel/oneapi-hpckit:${ONEAPI_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu18.04 AS oneapi-hpckit
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
      build-essential \
      cmake \
      ninja-build && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler
COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl
COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb
```

I built it twice using:

```bash
git clone <repo> repo
docker build \
  --build-arg http_proxy \
  --build-arg https_proxy \
  --build-arg no_proxy \
  --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
  --cache-from ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
  -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
  - < repo/Dockerfile
docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE}
docker rmi ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE}
docker image prune -f
rm -rf repo
git clone <repo> repo
docker build \
  --build-arg http_proxy \
  --build-arg https_proxy \
  --build-arg no_proxy \
  --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
  --cache-from ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
  -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
  - < repo/Dockerfile
```

In both instances all of the stages were cached, no stage was rebuilt.

These build steps have matching hashes:

```
#16 [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:478caf1bec1afd54a58435ec681c8755883b7eb843a8630091890130b15a79af
#16 sha256:f6e80c6e585e12e84ea064dc5bfbdde0762abb0f45c119d1c3c6b06ccf3c31db
#16 DONE 0.0s

#10 [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:478caf1bec1afd54a58435ec681c8755883b7eb843a8630091890130b15a79af
#10 sha256:f6e80c6e585e12e84ea064dc5bfbdde0762abb0f45c119d1c3c6b06ccf3c31db
#10 DONE 0.0s
```

```
#11 [oneapi-hpckit 1/1] FROM docker.io/intel/oneapi-hpckit:2022.1.2-devel-ubuntu18.04@sha256:f87d873d7de912c9f7d944cea1da057545d10fdd63970afb4389bc9f02037408
#11 sha256:555017ddeca0a3576363999f93ef738a8692e02ade19f1f177b9578f4f524c93
#11 DONE 0.0s

#12 [oneapi-hpckit 1/1] FROM docker.io/intel/oneapi-hpckit:2022.1.2-devel-ubuntu18.04@sha256:f87d873d7de912c9f7d944cea1da057545d10fdd63970afb4389bc9f02037408
#12 sha256:555017ddeca0a3576363999f93ef738a8692e02ade19f1f177b9578f4f524c93
#12 DONE 0.0s
```

These build steps have mismatching hashes:

```
#10 [stage-1 2/6] RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y       build-essential       cmake       ninja-build &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#10 sha256:7573e91567e9bfe53570e6ea939f129389b7e45feb076817817f751fab5619ab
#10 CACHED

#11 [stage-1 2/6] RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y       build-essential       cmake       ninja-build &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#11 sha256:ff984e2077208e0fe2c6312adb6ff8203fe87e722082b5dbc41c341c812e2624
#11 CACHED
```

```
#12 [stage-1 3/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
#12 sha256:393028c2915e599f51b32f595eacdea522dfcd5abe118df11e59aef593b13485
#12 CACHED

#13 [stage-1 3/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
#13 sha256:c56ddffb0433f94dbfcebe0858dc729c7bda25a342f95416d1651ba45618f05e
#13 CACHED
```

```
#13 [stage-1 4/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler
#13 sha256:d4b8865ff314458f268cb8bb4d0f049ebad5537fb3cf8b45802b9f63a44da007
#13 CACHED

#14 [stage-1 4/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler
#14 sha256:cba2dff7420415fa1cebc119bf845726143ba56af4431827b561dd012176a2fd
#14 CACHED
```

```
#14 [stage-1 5/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl
#14 sha256:a7ef5221a3a6a98c6191d2afa211e91a23bb23073973ac5bdb2404806714aeb1
#14 CACHED

#15 [stage-1 5/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl
#15 sha256:8d367ab53ddf708a0ce984aabee31f2ab6f9543b6fa8475d6f12db7bcfe16076
#15 CACHED
```

```
#15 [stage-1 6/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb
#15 sha256:1fa326be1295455c08fe072fb888b8c49cbde3f160161107eb237cb8d638ac10
#15 CACHED

#16 [stage-1 6/6] COPY --link --from=oneapi-hpckit /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb
#16 sha256:cd87f15a1299ebac4a0bc24f6d4434b74ff54c20ef85513747a8cb9b5b6dbb01
#16 CACHED
```

So the hashes deviate at `stage-1 2/6`, but in both cases they are cached from the remote registry (so not rebuilt), and stage-1 1/6 hashes are identical. Nothing beside that push updated the image in the registry in between these builds.

The imported cache manifest from the registry is the same for both builds (`sha256:0cf935a9ac4a10c138f2f7d52a92c850f55aa56827a794edb72997f628250f71`), and the metadata for both base images are also the same. The only difference I see between the build logs is the hashes for `[internal] load build definition from Dockerfile`, but I guarantee that the Dockerfile did not change between runs. The metadata may have changed on it, since each build was from a different git checkout, but I guarantee the file content is identical between checkouts.

How did these hashes deviate?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was a case of the local build cache having a different version of the image layers than the registry (in the `--cache-from`, and **one was chosen at random each time** (the image layers in the registry also existed in the local build cache). Before clearing the build cache on the machine with `docker builder prune -f`, which of the two layers that was used was random. After clearing the build cache, the same layer was used every time (from the registry).